# packing 6 bits integers into 1 64bit integer

Tags: compression, long-integer

The numbers I am interested in packing is between 0 and 55 inclusive. Clearly, in binary they need 6 bits each to represent, but 64 only divides 6 ten times.

My question is, is it possible to pack 11 numbers between 0 and 55 into 64bits?

Comment: Seems to be a general question... and not a type of coding issue.

Comment: Yes, because 56^11 < 2^64. (i.e.  treat it as an 11 digit number in base 56). |  Looking at it another way: log base 2 of 56 is roughly 5.81. Since 64/5.81 is slightly more than 11, the answer is yes.

Comment: @DanMašek Yup that's it! thank you sir